# How to concatenate foreach loop with **switch-case**

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a array with a few string values, and I correctly can out it in console:

```
for element in "${answers[@]}"
do echo $element
done
```

out:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 5

But I need do some command for each value in array:

For example this implementation does not execute any action:

```
for element in "${answers[@]}";
do 

#    switch $element {
    case $element in
       1)
        echo "install app 1";;
       2)
        echo "install app 2";;
       3)
        echo "install app 3 ";;
esac 
done
```

---

In follow attempt:

```
for element in "${answers[@]}";
do

    switch $element {
    case "1": echo "install app 1";;
    case "2": echo "install app 2";;
    case "3": echo "install app 3";;
}
done
```

I have exception:

> ./prepare_2.0.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
>   ./prepare_2.0.sh: line 15:`    case "1": echo "install app 1";;'

How to correctly implement this logic?

Comment: You have a typo in the variable name in the case statement "elemant"

Comment: @glennjackman Good catch!

Comment: @glennjackman, yes, it is just typo. I did correct this and what's next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You splits string value, but in first attempt you not use it. 
Just change '1)' to '"1")'

for element in "${answers[@]}";
do

```
case $element in
   "1")
    echo "install app 1";;
   "2")
    echo "install app 2";;
   "3")
    echo "install app 3 ";;
esac
```